# Prove that there exists a deterministic TM M1 that stops on every input and recognises the complement L ̅ of language L, that is L(M1) = L ̅.

Tags: algorithms

I have the following Problem:

Let us assume that the deterministic TM *M* stops on every input and *L(M) = L*. Prove that there exists a deterministic TM *M1* that stops on every input and recognizes the complement L ̅ of language L, that is L(*M1*) = L ̅ (complement of L)

Can anybody help me solve it please, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks dear Shaun